# Custom adapter in setview binder method simple cursor adapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to group cursor elements and show them in a list. Now i am not able to get the particular view in which the user has swiped kindly help me

```
@Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View v = convertView;
          final Item i = items.get(position);
          if (i != null) {
                 if(i.isSection()){
                       SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                       v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
                       final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                     //sectionView.setText(si.g);
                       sectionView.setText(si.getTaskType());
                       v.setOnClickListener(null);
                       v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                       v.setLongClickable(false);
                 }else{
                       EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
                       v = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, null);
                       final TextView tskTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taskTime);
                       final TextView tskName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.taskName);

                        if (tskTime != null) tskTime.setText(ei.getCategory());
                       if (tskName != null) tskName.setText(ei.getTaskName());
                 }
          }
          return v;
   }
```

[image: The screen shot of my screen]

Comment: There are multiple problems with this code like not recycling the views at all. What I really don't understand though, is what exactly your problem is. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: want to generate same like the screen shot in bind view in simple cursor adapter

Comment: Just to make sure i understood. You can make it work with a baseAdapter and you want to implement it inside a cursorAdapter?